# No output for Find and Replace in Files using Python Script

Tags: python, file, dictionary, replace, nested

Somehow I am getting no output in the new_code file.

I am trying to read the file.txt and make changes based on the dictionary values (find_replace_dic). The key of the dictionary are the words that are to be replaced by the dictionary values. The logic is working fine I tried that with print statements but somehow the new_code file is showing blank output.

The variable 'new_word' contains the new changes for each if and elif condition.

```
with open('file.txt','r') as file, open ('model_testing_1.txt','w') as new_code:
    for line in file:
        word = line.replace('\n',"").split('.')[-1]
        if ':' in word:
            old_model = word.strip().split(':')[-1]
            old_model_s = old_model.strip()
            for key in find_replace_dic:
                if old_model_s == key:
                    new_word =  line.replace(old_model_s, find_replace_dic.get(key))
                    print(new_word)
        elif ':' not in word:
            for key in find_replace_dic:
                if word == key:
                    new_word =  line.replace(word, find_replace_dic.get(key))
                    print(new_word)         
                      
new_code.close()
file.close()
```

Comment: you don't need the `.close()` when you are using `with`

Comment: you can also use `if word in find_replace_dic` instead of the whole for loop

Comment: @MZ it still returns nothing sadly.

Comment: @MZ the conditions are added because some words have '.' before them and some of them are to be picked after the colon and not otherwise.

Comment: Are you sure it is supposed to print something? Did you check

Comment: @MZ I am expecting a new file with all those changes lets say  I have two sentences in the the original file 1) the numbers are changed to zero. 2) the numbers are changed to 2. I would expect my new file to show two new sentences: 1) the numbers are changed to Null 2) the numbers are changed to two. Considering I have a dictionary which has keys zero and 2 and values as null and two

Comment: @MZ If I print the variable 'new words' it does show me the correct output (new lines meeting each if and Elif condition)  but the file is still empty somehow

Comment: Where are you writing to new_code?  Instead of `print(new_word)`, try `print(new_word, file=new_code)`

Comment: @mike67 print(new_word, file = new_code) does print the lines but it doesn't show the other lines which doesn't have any match. I want to get all the lines from the file file.txt which means the lines which now have new words and also the lines that were not changed at all. If I create an else statement  else: print(line, file = new_code) it also doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following the post correctly, the logic is this for each line in the source file:

- Split the line on '.', get the last element
- If the last element contains ':', further split the last element on ':', get the last element
- If the element is in the replace dictionary, replace the element from the dictionary
- Output the line with the replaced element

This code follows that logic:

```
data = '''
aaa1.bb:b1.ccc1.ddd1:eee1
aaa2.bb:b2.ccc2.ddd2:eee2
aaa3.bb:b3.ccc3.ddd3:eee3
aaa1:bbb1.ccc1:ddd1.eee1
aaa2:bbb2.ccc2:ddd2.eee2
'''.strip()

with open('file.txt','w') as f: f.write(data)  # test file

find_replace_dic = {'eee2':'zzz'}

################# Main Script ###################


with open('file.txt','r') as file, open ('model_testing_1.txt','w') as new_code:
    for line in file:
        word = line.replace('\n',"").split('.')[-1]
        if ':' in word:
            old_model = word.strip().split(':')[-1]
            old_model_s = old_model.strip()
            if old_model_s in find_replace_dic:
                line = line[:line.rindex(':')] + ':' + find_replace_dic[old_model_s]
        else: # ':' not in word
            if word in find_replace_dic:
                line = line[:line.rindex('.')] + '.' + find_replace_dic[word]
        print (line.strip())
        print (line.strip(), file=new_code)
                      
new_code.close()
file.close()
```

Output

```
aaa1.bb:b1.ccc1.ddd1:eee1
aaa2.bb:b2.ccc2.ddd2:zzz
aaa3.bb:b3.ccc3.ddd3:eee3
aaa1:bbb1.ccc1:ddd1.eee1
aaa2:bbb2.ccc2:ddd2.zzz
```

Comment: As of now there are multiple other cases as well. But that's correct. let's say there are lines and words for which we don't have the key / values in our dictionary so we also want them to stay as that - meaning no changes to be made just copy the original line and paste it in the new file.